# How to extract date out of string using date time

Tags: python, datetime

if for example I have a string like this

```
import datetime as datetime
string = "Hello todays date is 11/02/2022 thanks"
```

How may I use datetime to extract just the date and display is as Nov/2/2022. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Side note: How do you know that the author of that string (and other similar strings you may want to parse) did not actually mean "11th of February, 2022"? That's an ambiguous date format, without any locale information.

Answer (score 0):

Using python-dateutil:

```
In [1]: import dateutil.parser as dparser

In [18]: dparser.parse("Hello todays date is 11/02/2022 thanks", fuzzy=True)
Out[18]: datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 02, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [article](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime).

In your case solution looks like:

```py
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(
    string,
    "Hello todays date is %m/%d/%Y thanks"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only the standard library, you can find the date using a regex and then parse it with datetime.

```
import datetime
import re

string = "Hello todays date is 11/02/2022 thanks"

m = re.search(r"\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d", string)

if m:
    print(datetime.datetime.strptime(m[0], "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to import like this

```
from datetime import datetime
```

You can then use regex to get the date:

```
import re
string = "Hello todays date is 11/02/2022 thanks"
regex = re.findall(r'\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}', string)
```

This will return a list of all matches. You can then convert the matched strings:

```
d_time = datetime.strptime(regex[0], '%m/%d/%y')
```